# Order files in a folder by numerical value instead of string

Tags: c#, linq, file

Trying something like this to sort all my files in a directory by numerical value of file names not string.

```
var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(outputDirectory, "*.txt").OrderBy(f => int.Parse(f));
```

filesnames in the folder are like

```
1.txt
2.txt
```

etc

But getting error "Input format not in correct format"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to parse whole file name to integer (but file name looks like `"C:\foo\bar\2.txt"`). Use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get only number part of your file name (for sample name I provided, it returns `"2"`):

```
var txtFiles = Directory
                   .GetFiles(outputDirectory, "*.txt")
                   .OrderBy(f => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)));
```

Side note: you can use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid file names array creation while enumerating files.